# Get device's component information and health status

Tags: adb

Is there any option provided by Android by which we can list down all the hardware and software component of smart phone? Also, we can check the health staus of all the hardware components. For example, battrey, wifi, camera etc. If the battrey is 50% charged then it should show the user about battrey current health. Its hould also tell if all other components are working fine or not, like wifi, bluetooth, RAM,ROM etc.

Is there any existing app for the same. If not then, what all things I need to know to build this app.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a number of tools available over the store that can help you in detecting the health status, try using [Z-Device Test](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=zausan.zdevicetest&hl=en) available over the store.